# How to mock, or otherwise test readPassword?

Tags: java, scala, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I'm developing a framework for simplifying the creation of console applications. My framework is written in Scala, and I'm using ScalaTest and Mockito for unit testing.

I need to be able to mock `java.io.Console`, but it's declared final. I'm trying to achieve 100% unit test coverage is currently this is the only thing blocking me - in both functional and unit tests.

So far I've not been able to get very far with any solution, I just can't think of a way of doing this. It doesn't implement an interface that I can mock, the method isn't available anywhere else, obviously I can't extend it. I'm thinking perhaps there's a solution that could involve some sort of dynamic method of calling the methods like `readLine` and `readPassword`, but I'm not experienced enough to get anywhere with that train of thought either!

Comment: 100% coverage is the biggest illusion in CS, Abraham Lincoln :)

Comment: Have you considered looking at SystemRules (http://stefanbirkner.github.io/system-rules/index.html), its a set of junit rules for dealing with the System class.  It might give you some inspiration.  Alternatively perhaps ScalaCheck could offer some help in this case, its a different approach to testing.

Comment: @SleimanJneidi I have no doubt you're correct there! :) It'd still be interesting to know if there is a solution to this, it seems like a bit of an oversight in API design in Java, I've not encountered something like this yet.

Comment: This is probably a more general problem - I suggest renaming the question to "How to mock, or otherwise test, final and static methods" in order to attract more answers.

Answer (score 1):

You should create your own interface to wrap all interactions with `java.io.Console`, e.g.

```
public interface ConsoleService {
    ...
}
```

So long as you only interact with the console via an instance of `ConsoleService`, then you will be able to mock the `ConsoleService` and test 99% of your code as you normally would. The `ConsoleService` interface becomes the boundary of your application for both functional testing of the entire app and the unit tests of the classes that interact with it directly.

Now we have reduced the scope of the problem to "how do I test the `ConsoleService` implementation", and we need to get a little creative. For example, you could redirect Console output to a file and inspect the contents of the file. You might not even want to test the `ConsoleService` in Scala; you could write a skeleton application using the `ConsoleService` then use your scripting language of choice to start a real Console on your favourite OS, interact with your skeleton application and test the `ConsoleService` that way. You can get as creative (and hacky) as you like here because:

1. it only affects a small number of tests; and
2. your application will likely mature to a point where the `ConsoleService` implementation doesn't need to change very much, i.e. your wacky testing solution will not be a great burden on future developers.

For these reasons it should be obvious that it is a good idea to keep the `ConsoleService` wrapper **very thin** because any logic in there will be tested via the strange `ConsoleService` tests, not nice friendly Scala tests. Often direct delegation to `java.io.Console` methods is good enough, but you should allow your application's functional tests to drive out the `ConsoleService` interface rather than making any presumptions (your functional test assertions will likely rely on particular interactions with a mock `ConsoleService`, or perhaps on the state of a stub, test implementation of `ConsoleService` which you can control in the test).

Finally, you may decide that the `ConsoleService`wrapper is *so* thin that its implementation does require any unit/functional tests at all. The implementation of `ConsoleService` will likely be so critical to your application that any defects will be exposed by integration tests or manual inspection of the app in UAT.

You might end up with something like this (apologies, I don't speak Scala so it's Java):

```
public class RealConsoleService implements ConsoleService {
    private final java.io.Console delegate;
    public RealConsoleService(java.io.Console delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public String readLine() throws IOError {
        return delegate.readLine();
    }
}
```

Two interesting points:

- This is a great example of why test driven development helps write flexible code. If you wanted to rewrite your framework using another method of input and output, you would just rename `ConsoleService` to the more abstract `ApplicationInputOutputService` and plug in a different implementation.
- The same concept can be used to test applications that use other difficult-to-test APIs. Many of Java's useful file IO methods are static methods and therefore difficult to control in tests. By wrapping in an interface as above, your application functionality becomes easy to test.